# Magento2:cannot remove 'generated/.htaccess': Permission denied

Tags: magento2

From this user  on fresh installation impossible run any command in terminal.

```
[user@s1 public_html]$ bin/magento c:f
Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist
[user@s1 public_html]$
```

When I try delete example generated folder `Permission denied`:

```
[user@s1 public_html]$ [fsgroup@s1 public_html]$ rm -rf generated
[user@s1 public_html]$ rm: cannot remove 'generated/.htaccess': Permission denied
```

When I try add privileges to files/folders:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento2/ 
chmod 777 -R var
chmod 777 -R generated
chmod 777 -R app/etc
```

also return this user not have  privileges to use this command. How to solve issue and how to give privileges to user?

Comment: it owner ship  issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first - files&folders ownership - You either swap to root user in order to execute the change the ownership command, or you add the current user in the sudoers group.

Next, running magento commands - you should always run magento cli commands using the webserver user (www-data) and not root or other user, otherwise you end up in the same situation you are now in.